# Installing/adding templates on Microsoft Visual Web Developer

Tags: c#, templates, web, installation

I have been trying to install/add a template I downloaded into Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010. I have looked around but could not find an option to install the templates. How can one install it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Project" menu, click "Properties" at the bottom, under "Output Type:" select "Console Application".